# I have robotframework=3.1.2 but it says Found: 2.9

Tags: eclipse, plugins, robotframework, version

I am clonned a project from bitbucket and opened it in the VS Code Editor. I installed Robot Framework Language Server Plugin. Then I saw this:

[Expected Robot Framework version: 3.2. Found: 2.9 robotframework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWCE5.png)

Then I checked the robotframework version I had by using this command

`pip show robotframework`

in the terminal and it says

[Version: 3.1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omvVW.png)

I am aware that in order to use this plugin, I will have to up robotframework version but it is not recognizing correct version.

Therefore, none of the library used are getting recognized.Can someone please suggest a solution so that it recognizes correct version and hence the libraries used.

I even tried in Eclipse and Pycharm same issue.

Comment: For such old versions of robotframework, I recommend to use RIDE from `https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/` .  About VSCode plugins, I doubt they work correctly for that old version, because syntax changes. And maybe you need to use Python 3.